# Operator overload stops working in R package

Tags: r, overloading, devtools, r-s3

I have a container class that is basically a list. Because I wanted to support subsetting, I have overloaded the subset `[` operator (likely poorly implemented).

```
#' Constructor for spectra object
.spectra = function(n_spectrum = 0) {
    object        = vector(mode = "list", n_spectrum)
    class(object) = "spectra"
    return(object)
}

#' Operator overload
#' @export
`[.spectra` = function(x, i) {
    x = unclass(x)
    x = x[i]                  # Using the list's subset function
    class(x) = "spectra"
    return(x)                 # Should return a "spectra" object, not a list
}
```

Now, this works as expected when in my development environment (when I'm debugging the package). That is, if `y_old` is a `spectra` object and I do `y_new = y_old[-1]`, `y_new` is still a `spectra` object.

However, **when I compile the project as a package and install it**, the subsetting operator returns a `list` instead of a `spectra` object.

Any clue of what is going on?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I'm using RStudio and the `devtools` library.

Comment: Do you have a line with `S3method("[",spectra)` in the `NAMESPACE` file of your package?

Comment: @nicola No. The **only** line I have in `NAMESPACE`  is `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")`, which I guess is what RStudio puts in there.

Comment: Put that line, rebuild the package and see if it works.

Comment: @nicola This does work, though I'm curious why that is the only function that doesn't get exported automatically.

Comment: It doesn't match your pattern in `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")`. That looks for functions that start with letters. This particular function starts with a "["

Comment: Thanks, that answer helped me. You should make it official so this question can be closed and we can upvote the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem boils down to RStudio's default initialization of NAMESPACE when you choose to create a package. Inspecting the NAMESPACE file reveals:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

Which doesn't match the subset operator `[`, as MrFlick pointed out.

You can either add names to NAMESPACE manually or you can get RStudio and Roxygen to do the work for you. In RStudio 0.99.902 you would:

1. `install.packages("roxygen2")`
2. Check **Generate documentation with Roxygen** in the menu **Build** > **Configure Build Tools** > **Build Tools**.
3. Click on the **Configure** button and check the **NAMESPACE file** check box.

Now you obviously have to add Roxygen documentation to your functions and remember to use the `@export` tag, e.g.:

```
#' Print hi in R
#' @export
print_hi = function(x) print("hi")
```

After building you should have a automatically generated NAMESPACE file. For instance:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(print_hi)
```